# Updating Column Values using DateLine

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my sql table

```
create table Poll_Question_Table (
PollQuestionId int primary key,
PollQuestionTex varchar(max),
PollStatus int ,
PollStartDate date,
PollEndDate date
)
```

i Want to change th status value from 1 to 0 if the current date pass the end date (dateline ) using function or trigger ..... tnx for ur help

Comment: Post the code that you ever try. You can't beg for code.

Comment: Are you asking SO to create a function or trigger code for you or have you tried doing it yourself first?

Comment: i tried this one

Comment: What is wrong with whatever you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of the 2 triggers given below under OPTION 1 or OPTION 2. I am assuming that your tables exists under the `dbo` schema; if not, then replace `dbo` by the appropriate schema name.

If you prefer using your function then go for OPTION 2. If you use OPTION 1 then you do not need to use your `dateLine` function.

(*NOTE about your `dateLine` function*: Keep in mind that your `dateLine` function is not truly checking if current date has exceeded the poll end date, which could be an issue if you use OPTION 2.)

The trigger would fire after either an insert or update operation.

**OPTION 1**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.changeStatus ON dbo.Poll_Question_Table AFTER
INSERT,
UPDATE AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @pollEndDate datetime,
        @pollQuestionId int;


SELECT @pollQuestionId= i.PollQuestionId,
       @pollEndDate = i.PollEndDate
FROM Inserted i;


UPDATE dbo.Poll_Question_Table
SET PollStatus = CASE
                     WHEN GetDate() > @pollEndDate THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                 END
WHERE PollQuestionId = @pollQuestionId and PollStatus = 1;

GO
```

You can also create a trigger using your function as below.

**OPTION 2**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.changeStatus ON dbo.Poll_Question_Table AFTER
INSERT,
UPDATE AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @pollEndDate datetime,
        @pollQuestionId int;


SELECT @pollQuestionId= i.PollQuestionId,
       @pollEndDate = i.PollEndDate
FROM Inserted i;


UPDATE dbo.Poll_Question_Table
SET PollStatus = dbo.dateLine(@pollEndDate)
WHERE PollQuestionId = @pollQuestionId and PollStatus = 1;

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i tried

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dateLine(@PollEndDate date)  
RETURNS int   
AS   
-- Returns the stock level for the product.  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @ret int;
DECLARE @Now date
set @Now = GETDATE()
    if((SELECT DATEDIFF (day,@PollEndDate,@Now) AS DiffDate)>0)
        set @ret= 1;
       return @ret;  
END
```

Comment: You can just use a trigger in your case and there is no need of a function. I have given the code for trigger in my answer.

Comment: Also, you are only checking for `day` difference but current date can exceed the end date by just a few hours. So is your requirement valid only if current date exceeds end date by 1 day or more, or it's valid even when current date is ahead by a few hours or minutes or seconds?